# Windows 10 update 1803 renamed the user account folder with .000 suffix

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, user-profiles, windows-10-v1803

I installed the `Windows 10 update version 1803` yesterday night. Some time later, I realized that for some reason, it had renamed my original User's folder with a `.000` suffix. My user account name is still the same. There is now a new folder with the original username, but there are only a couple of folders inside it. All of the documents, downloads, application data, etc. is inside the folder suffixed with the `.000`. Opening the `cmd` prompt opens directly into the folder with the `.000` suffix.

I am able to login to my account, see desktop icons, etc. However some apps that expect data to be in the folder without the suffix are unable to load their settings. For example, Notepad++ cannot load its last saved session. Also, unable to browse downloaded files through Firefox.

I'd like to have my User folder back without the `.000` suffix. Could someone tell me how. I haven't seen anything on Microsoft acknowledging this and haven't come across any fix for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you was using a Microsoft account to login, then upgrade system to 1803 version.

Try to roll back to the previous Windows version.

Sign-in your PC with a local account.

Upgrade again under the local account.

Note, don’t use built-in Administrator account as local account.

Reference:

Why user profile is C:\Users\ username_000 (truncated username and underscore)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/37c266c0-0124-4fb1-83b7-8bde4db986b0/why-user-profile-is-cusers-username000-truncated-username-and-underscore?forum=w8itprogeneral

Comment: Nope. I was not using a Microsoft account. I was using a local account.

Comment: @Origami how to roll back to the previous Windows version?

Comment: I was using a Microsoft account, rolling back fixed the issue. I'm not keen on retrying the update any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when the old profile path is inaccessible. There are a number of reasons for this such as changing the computer's SID or even the old profile not being properly unloaded or wrong ownership or DACLs. This has been the case since at least Windows NT 4, btw.

With the registry editor of your choice go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$SID`, where `$SID` is the placeholder for the SID of the account which shows the behavior you describe. You can see which SID corresponds to your account by asking `wmic useraccount get name,sid`. Typically the one ending in `-500` is the built-in (local) admin account and `-1000` the first created user account. These numbers (500 and 1000 respectively) are called RIDs (relative IDs).

Inside said registry key locate the value for `ProfileImagePath` and adjust as needed.

[image: Profile settings for built-in admin]

Please note that if the profile still exists under the old path (without `.000`) and is still inaccessible (say due to ownership or DACLs) you may run into a situation where WinLogon will simply create another new profile (presumably with `.001` suffix). Although I have not seen it on modern Windows versions, there's a chance you may lock yourself out by tampering with the `ProfileImagePath` value, so I suggest you keep a secondary account active and available (e.g. the built-in admin account).

As mentioned, this should be the same procedure for anything from NT 4 onward. However, possible that Microsoft introduced new rules for these Microsoft (online) accounts which you can use. Also the SIDs look different when dealing with domain accounts.

Comment: Adjusting the value of `ProfileImagePath` makes Windows unable to login to the account.

Comment: I do not have the `-500`admin account, only the `-1001` user account, which ends with `.000`. The old profile path contains a few things:
`C:.
└───Search
    └───Data
        ├───Applications
        │   └───Windows
        └───Temp
            └───usgthrsvc` and when I want to delete it it says it's opened in another program... My current favorite game is broken because of that

Comment: I think you should go back to the previous Windows version, remove all the folders (or back them up) that currently remain in the old user directory and try the upgrade again. See my proposed solution at https://superuser.com/a/1321082/73039.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on updating to 1903.

From what I read here, Zune can end up locking some user files which interferes with the upgrade process.  Suggestion is to try rolling back the update (if you still can), then try removing Zune before updating again.  You can also just disable the performance trace inside Performance Monitor (you'll see it inside Data Collector Sets -> Startup Event Trace Sessions...open up the WMZuneComm entry, go to the Trace Session tab, and uncheck "Enabled").

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/updated-to-1903-but-user000-now-created-and-holds/06636b30-9838-4c5e-b236-dc1d06f2f175?page=4

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-update-1903-renames-user-fiolder/050a0bbe-a9b1-4a16-8239-7b7a9852022a?page=4

Other things that seemed to be giving me trouble (as evidenced by those files remaining in the "old" profile folder):

1. relocating my favorites directory into OneDrive (I temporarily reset it to default)
2. Team Foundation Server Power Tools shell extension (I temporarily removed that feature)

Comment: This actually happened on a Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 upgrade too.  I'm glad I encountered it here first because I would never have figured it out.  The error was "User profile suffix mismatch, upgrade cannot continue: The specified profile is intended for a device of a different type than the specified device. [0x000007E7]", which basically meant the profile now had the ".000" suffix because of locked files.

Answer (score -1):

Make a safe copy of your profile from C:\Users Next go to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList and remove the entry for the profile. Reboot. Sign back in as a new user. Access the back up you made and copy everything over to the user folder just created. Reinstall applications as necessary, etc. It's a little bit of work, but this is the only way I could get rid of the 000 issue. Smooth sailing!