# New user profile, can't rollback? - Windows 10 Update April 2018 (1803)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, user-profiles, windows-10-v1803

I've just updated my Windows 10 to the April 1803 version, to find a new user profile established in place of my old Windows login. The `/mr_g.MR-G` directory is the now currently used profile, which is a typical, fresh default profile (nothing imported or used from `/mr_g`)

[image: Image of C:/Users directory.]

I had previously set up many variables, such as modifying `temp` and AppData (`Local`, `LocalLow` and `Roaming`) folder locations to a larger HDD, off the SSD to save space. These are no longer setup with the fresh update.

**Is there an easy way to ensure profile crossover with the update?**

I've tried to rollback, however I'm prompted when using "`Go back to the previous version of Windows 10`" to remove new accounts.

[image: Image of remove user accounts prompt.]

Unfortuantely Windows 10 no longer recognises the old login profile, and thus **only** the new account exists, and presumably can't be easily removed.

[image: Image of non-existant 'other people' list.]

There also seems to be a 'sign in with local account' option under `Your Info`, but this also seems to be an account creation wizard.

The behaviour seems related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1318983/windows-10-update-1803-renamed-the-user-account-folder-with-000-suffix/1319580) question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you can really do is copy over the files (documents, pictures, music files, etc) to the new profile and set up all your stuff again.

It might be enough to copy the entire `C:\Users\Old_Username` folder,
except the following files (whichever ones you can see, as some are hidden):

- Ntuser.dat
- Ntuser.dat.log*
- Ntuser.ini